# Import Data command in Enthought Canopy fails with: “The Data Import Tool requires..."

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, enthought, canopy

Import Data command in Enthought Canopy fails with:

> The Data Import Tool requires that the Canopy Python kernel be running in Pylab mode with Qt4 interactive backend. You can change back to this setting in your Canopy preferences (Python tab).

I have changed the stated settings in preferences as the error message suggests.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Python 3.5, perhaps you didn't install the PyQt packages? If you are a subscriber, please feel free to submit a feedback report from the Canopy Help menu which will provide Enthought with your configuration info. (If you are not a logged-in subscriber, then the Data Import Tool is not supported anyway, though I would not expect this error message in that case.)